# create a list of screens in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

i want to navigate through multiple screens when the item is clicked on the drawer, but i get an error everytime i add a screen that has a parameter in the list.

```
final List<Widget> Screens = [
    Home(),
    Search(),
    Compose(contacts),
    Favourite(contacts),
    Inbox(),
  ];
```

i call it in the body of my main.dart scaffold like

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        drawer: SideBar(_changeIndexNumber),
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
          elevation: 0,
          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
          title: TextField(
            style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Footlight',
                color: Colors.white,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: UnderlineInputBorder(), hintText: 'Search...'),
          ),
          actions: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 2, 5, 2),
              child: Icon(Icons.logout_outlined),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 0),
          child: Screens[screenIndex],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

link to the full code https://github.com/BuffyJoe/Email-App-Flutter.git

**EDITED TO SHOW SIDEBAR**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SideBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function _changeIndexNumber;

  SideBar(this._changeIndexNumber);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
      child: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        children: [
          const DrawerHeader(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
              accountEmail: Text('okaforbestkid@gmail.com'),
              accountName: Text('O.Emmanuel'),
              currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                child: ClipOval(
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/new.jpg'),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    height: 90,
                    width: 90,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage('assets/images/chatbackground.png'),
                    fit: BoxFit.fill),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.login),
            title: Text('Log-in'),
            onTap: () {
              _changeIndexNumber(1);
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.home_filled),
            title: Text('Home'),
            onTap: () {
              _changeIndexNumber(0);
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                ExpansionTile(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.all_inbox_rounded),
                  title: Text('All Messages'),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.expand_more_outlined),
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: 400,
                      child: ListView(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 2, 2, 2),
                        children: [
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Icon(Icons.inbox_rounded),
                            title: Text('Primary'),
                            onTap: null,
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Icon(Icons.people_outline_outlined),
                            title: Text('Social'),
                            onTap: null,
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Icon(
                              Icons.label,
                            ),

                            title: Text('Promotions'),
                            // style: ListTileStyle.list,
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Icon(
                              Icons.info,
                            ),
                            title: Text('Spam'),
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Icon(Icons.drafts),
                            title: Text('Drafts'),
                            onTap: null,
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Icon(Icons.send),
                            title: Text('Sent'),
                            onTap: null,
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Icon(Icons.label),
                            title: Text('Proposal'),
                            onTap: null,
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Icon(Icons.inbox_rounded),
                            title: Text('Primary'),
                            onTap: null,
                          ),
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Icon(
                              Icons.star_border_purple500_rounded,
                            ),
                            title: Text('starred'),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(
                    Icons.contact_mail,
                  ),
                  title: Text('Contacts'),
                  onTap: () {
                    _changeIndexNumber(4);
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(
                    Icons.settings,
                  ),
                  title: Text('Settings'),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading: Icon(
                    Icons.local_activity_rounded,
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    'Activity',
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    _changeIndexNumber(2);
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: [Use this Link](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/named-routes) to navigate betwee screens. if you share `SideBar` maybe i can help you.

Answer (score 0):

make the final variable:
VoidCallback ontap;
then call on ontap in gesture GestureDetector like this:

```
 GestureDetector(
          onTap: ontap,
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
            size: 18,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        )
```

make list on main class scaflod like this:

```
final screens = [
    EditProfile(),
    BottomModel(),
    Orders(),
    ProductList(),
    
  ];
```

then call list on navigator like this:

```
   ontap: () {
        Navigator.push(
      context,
   MaterialPageRoute(
     uilder: (_) => screens[index]));
     },
```